# проблема при парсинге python

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup

подскажите пожалуйста:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json

headers = {'User-Agent':
'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linu…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0'
}

url = 'https://koleso.ru/shops/?region=all'

def parse_koleso(url):
    session = requests.Session()

    request = session.get(url)

    soup = bs(request.content, 'lxml')
    divs = soup.find('div', class_='shopList').find_all('a')

    full_links_cities = [x.get("href") for x in divs][0:-1]
    return full_links_cities

def shop_links(full_links_cities):
    session = requests.Session()
    a_list = []
    for city in full_links_cities:
        request1 = requests.get(city)

        soup = bs(request1.content, 'lxml')

        shops_list = soup.find('div', class_ = 'currentShopList')

        shops_list_2 = shops_list.find_all('a')
        a_list.append(shops_list_2)
     print(a_list)

    my_list = []
    for i in a_list:
         link = 'https://koleso.ru' + i.get('href')
         my_list.append(link)
```

проблема в том, что print(a_list) в конце листа появляется none, а в цикле:

```
my_list = []
for i in a_list:
   link = 'https://koleso.ru' + i.get('href')
   my_list.append(link)
```

не могу пройти по циклу, создать link. выбивает ошибку "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчёт первой ошибки с `%s` - этого я в приведённом коде не вижу.

Насчёт второй ошибки `AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'`:

Замените:

```
a_list.append(shops_list_2)
```

на

```
a_list += shops_list_2
```

Пример для понимания:

```
>>> test = [1,2]
>>> test2 = [3,4]
>>> test.append(test2)
>>> test
[1, 2, [3, 4]]

>>> test = [1,2]
>>> test2 = [3,4]
>>> test += test2
>>> test
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Ещё, в приведённом коде `print(a_list)` ни при каких условиях не может напечатать `None`. Похоже, Вы привели не весь код или не совсем тот код.

Я подозреваю, что изначально у Вас был код с `find`:

```
shops_list_2 = shops_list.find('a')
a_list.append(shops_list_2)
```

При таком коде действительно нужен `append()` и действительно в `a_list` может оказаться `[None]` при единственном проходе цикла...

Теперешний Ваш код - более правильный с точки зрения надежности. Вот только на `+=` замените, как я подсказал...

Answer (score -1):

У тебя ошибка в парсинге. "Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" значит то, что ты использовал `find()`, который находит единственный элемент, а элемент не один, следовательно ты должен использовать `findall()`

Comment: Неправильный ответ, потому что неправильный перевод. Правильный перевод: "Действительно ли вы хотели вызвать find_all(), а не find()". То есть использовался find_all(), а программа предлагает использовать вместо него find()

Comment: Более понятный перевод: "Вы вызывали find_all(). Действительно ли вы хотели вызвать его, а не find()?"